# Table number referencing

Tags: floats, numbering

I have a dissertation with three chapters, and each chapter has the table after main text and appendix. Each appendix has also table. The format is as follows:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} 
    \begin{document}
    \include{chapter1}
    \include{chapter2}
    \include{chapter3}
    \end{document}
```

Following is the reproducible example.:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[top=2.54 cm, bottom=2.54 cm, left=2.54 cm, right=2.54 cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % put before apacite
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

% chapter 1
\chapter{chapter1}\label{chp:This is chapter1}

\section{Introduction}
This paper examines
\section{Results}
\par Table \ref{tab:tab1} also indicates. But Appendix Table \ref{tab:apptab1}
\par Table \ref{tab:tab2} also indicates But Appendix Table \ref{tab:apptab2}
\section{\label{sec_conc} Conclusion}

% Tables

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{table 1}}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
       \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:tab1}%
\end{table}%


\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{table 1}}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
       \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:tab2}%
\end{table}%

%Appendix 
\clearpage
\newpage
\section*{Appendix A}
%\begin{appendices}
% Appendix 1A
  \begin{subappendices}
\section{\label{sec_appa}Increase in unemployment }

%renumber appendix tables
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{1A\arabic{table}}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{table 1}}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
       \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:apptab1}%
\end{table}%
% Appendix 1B   
\section{\label{sec_appb}Increase in unemployment }

%renumber appendix tables
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{1B\arabic{table}}


\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{table 1}}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
       \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:apptab2}%
\end{table}%
\end{subappendices}



% chapter 2

\chapter{chapter2}\label{chp:this is chapter2}

\section{Introduction}
This paper examines
\section{Results}

\par Table \ref{tab:tab1} also indicates. But Appendix Table \ref{tab:apptab1}
\par Table \ref{tab:tab2} also indicates But Appendix Table \ref{tab:apptab2}

\section{\label{sec_conc} Conclusion}


\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{table 1}}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
       \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:tab1}%
\end{table}%

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{table 1}}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
       \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:tab2}%
\end{table}%


%Appendix 
\clearpage
\newpage
\section*{Appendix A}
%\begin{appendices}
  \begin{subappendices}

% Appendix 2A   
\section{\label{sec_appa}Increase in unemployment }

%renumber appendix tables
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{2A\arabic{table}}
%appendix tables
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{table 1}}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
       \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:apptab1}%
\end{table}%

% Appendix 2B
\section{\label{sec_appb}Increase in unemployment}
%renumber appendix tables
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{2B\arabic{table}}
%appendix tables
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{table 1}}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
       \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:apptab2}%
\end{table}%
\end{subappendices}


\end{document}
```

There is an error when referencing to the table.

Comment: I think you have the numbering wrong that you say is output. Instead of the code snippets, we'd appreciate it if you could provide the community with a cohesive [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Make it so that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile as see exactly what you're seeing...

Comment: @Werner I have updated with the reproducible example.  Now, the error is in referencing.

Comment: What is this error? I test your MWE and it not gives any error.

Comment: The error is in referencing Table. In both chapters, we have `Table 2.3 also indicates. But Appendix Table 2A1`; it should be `Table 1.1 also indicates. But Appendix Table 1A1` for chapter 1, and `Table 2.1 also indicates. But Appendix Table 2A1` should be chapter 2.

Comment: @Metrics: The obvious problem here is that you can't use the same `\label` in two different locations. LaTeX mentions this by giving the *Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure what is your problem. Appearing of references to table in appendix? So see, if this will help you:

- in preamble add package `{chngcntr}` and select numbering within section:

  `\usepackage{chngcntr}
  \counterwithin{table}{section}`
- after `\begin{subappendices}` add:

  `\counterwithin{table}{section}`
- after each section in appendices reset table counter:

  `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}`

With this I obtain the following result:

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Complete code (slightly shortened):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.54 cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{chngcntr}% <----
\counterwithin{table}{section}% <----
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % put before apacite

    \begin{document}
    % chapter 1
\chapter{First chapter}
\label{chp:chapter-1}

\section{Introduction}
This paper examines \dots

\section{Results}
\par Table \ref{tab:tab1} also indicates. But Appendix Table \ref{tab:apptab1}
\par Table \ref{tab:tab2} also indicates But Appendix Table \ref{tab:apptab2}

\section{Conclusion}
\label{sec:conc} 
% Tables
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
\caption{\textbf{table 1}}
\label{tab:tab1}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  %
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
\caption{\textbf{table 2}}
\label{tab:tab2}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
       \end{tabular}
\end{table}%


%Appendix
\clearpage
\newpage
%\section*{Appendix A}
  \begin{subappendices}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}

\section{Increase in unemployment }
\label{sec_appa}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
\caption{\textbf{table A1}
\label{tab:apptab1}}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

% Appendix 1B
\section{Increase in unemployment }
\label{sec_appb}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
\caption{\textbf{table B1}}
\label{tab:apptab2}%
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1989}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1992}} \\
    \hline
          & income1 & expenses1 & income2 & expenses2 \\
                    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{subappendices}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: If you add another chapter, you will notice the problem. But, as @Werner said, I probably need to change label. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Where to add another chapter? Given example doesn't exhibits any problem with referencing regardless on number of chapters. Of course, labels should be **unique**. That is basic requirements for use referencing!.

Comment: You are correct. That was my problem. Once again, thank you for your solution. I will mark it as correct.